# Labels only for nodes with a minimal weight of x in Gephi

Tags: gephi

I have a network with ca. 3500 nodes and ca. 10000 edges. I'd like to show only labels for nodes with a certain weight, for example all with more than 100 edges. How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- First, you need to make sure the label view is activated for nodes (in the toolbar below the graph view).
- Second, you need to compute the weight of the nodes, using whatever statistics you want. In the Statistics tab, simply click Run on the particular metrics you want.
- Third, in the Filters tab, drag Attributes/Range/-your metrics- down to the Queries section, and choose the appropriate settings (in your case 100 to max.) using the slider on the bottom. You can view the exact numbers of the slider by clicking the "+" next to your Parameters. Click Run to run your filter and hide less important nodes.
- Fourth, click the "A->" icon just under the Filters tab. This will hide all labels that don't match your filter query.

[image: image of the button]

Image from *Sébastien Heymann, [Hide labels from filters result](https://gephi.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/gephi-0-7beta-released/filtersexportlabels/)*.

- Finally, remove the filter you created for label filtering by right-clicking it and selecting "Remove".